# Did my contractor install these windows correctly?

Tags: windows, contractors, window-frame

I had a contractor come install 4 of these windows for me.

He’s an older guy who I believe just does this to keep busy post retirement. The labor costs were very cheap.

When I went upstairs afterwards to look at the windows I immediately noticed what looks to me like a big problem with them.

So essentially these new windows are inserted into the old ones. However they aren’t the same thickness and there’s a gap between the front of the new window and the front of the old one.

Wouldn’t this gap just fill with water and run down my walls eventually and rot out? I can see pink insulation in the gap and it’s seemingly just exposed to the elements.

Thank you[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if you can see insulation, then yes, that's a problem.

Comment: Did he address any of this in the estimate?

Comment: Do you have unusually thick walls? Are they unusually thin replacement windows? A little wider shot showing the whole window frame & trim on one side would be helpful.

Comment: @JACK none of the specifics were mentioned. Like I said he’s an older retired guy. He gave me a price, had me order through his supplier, then he came and installed them.

Comment: @FreeMan they’re not unusually thick walls. These windows seem to just be slide-in inserts, I believe. But they’re definitely too “thin” so the old frame part of the window is still there. This whole thing seems very off.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I think you need a different tradesman. It’s possible that someone competent can make your windows function, but this guy hasn’t exactly demonstrated this skill. My intuition is that the windows you bought aren’t going to work, but I’d be happy if I was mistaken.

Comment: Biggest issue I see is there is no actual window in that frame.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should have been flashed first. Definitely call him back. Hope you didn't pay him the final.

EDIT: flashing is usually thin formed aluminum sheet metal used to divert water flow. One would want to divert water away from the framing and over the siding.

Comment: A little more meat could make this a good answer. Help the OP out and explain what "flashed" means. TBH, though, this requires more than just some flashing.

Comment: Thank you. The whole thing took about 2-3 hours. I paid cash (very cheap price). 

I’ll call him up, but it seems like it may be a you get what you pay for situation

Comment: They should be using a sticky, rubbery membrane material (think a gasket layer) before laying down any house wrap or aluminum sills.

Comment: Yeah we use that a lot. Peel and stick comes on a roll.

Answer (score 0):

There is good and bad news.

The bad news is that your installation was done improperly. At the very least flashing tape should have been used. Additionally, I do not see any weep holes or other means of drainage for this channel.

With such a large gap flashing tape is not sufficient and metal flashing should be used and allowances made for proper draining.  (slope, weep holes)

So yes, your windows should be removed and reinstalled with flashing.
Alternatively, your windows could be removed and reinstalled further out and interior trim added to hide the gap on the inside. Either is an option.

The good news is that what you see here is exterior closed-cell insulation. These are generally installed over the top of your exterior sheathing. This is the reason you can see it. Your window is installed in the framing opening and these panels extend past this. These panels are weather proof so will not absorb water. (Although water can get behind the panel next to the sheathing.) So while it needs to be fixed you are not in any immediate danger of causing rot.